# Wordpress Wysiwg editor not working in 4.2.2

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I've recently upgraded a site for the Add Media button wasn't working. Now, having upgraded to 4.2.2 the Add Media works, but the Wysiwyg editor isn't showing.

The only console messages I'm receiving are:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: edButtons is not defined (anonymous
>   function) @   post-new.php:131

The new post screen appears with the Text tab selected, instead of Visual, and when I try to select the Visual tab I get:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'canvas' of undefined
>   a.closeAllTags @ quicktags.min.js?ver=4.2.2:1 window.switchEditors.go
>   @ editor.min.js?ver=4.2.2:1 window.switchEditors.switchto @
>   editor.min.js?ver=4.2.2:1 onclick @ post-new.php:405

Any ideas?